# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'main'

Tags: python-2.7

I installed habo malware hunter, but when i ran it,i got following errors:

```
habo@habo-VirtualBox:~/HaboMalHunter$ sudo python AnalyzeControl.py -z -l ./test_0813.zip Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AnalyzeControl.py", line 688, in <module>
    ret = main(len(sys.argv), sys.argv)
  File "AnalyzeControl.py", line 615, in main
    cfg = init_arguments(argv)
  File "AnalyzeControl.py", line 156, in init_arguments
    cfg = init_cfg(args.config_path,args)
  File "AnalyzeControl.py", line 96, in init_cfg
    for k,v in conf_parser.items(SECTION_DEF):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 642, in items
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'main'
```

Comment: how is your config file format? it should be [main] \n conf=val \n conf=val

Comment: how and where to check config file format?

Comment: it should be specified in args.config_path, which defaults to config.ini you can see it in https://github.com/Tencent/HaboMalHunter/blob/master/config.ini, so you need to run from the directory that contain config.ini or specify path --config-path <path-to-config>